# Custom AsyncTaskLoader, loadinBackground not called after 5 attempts

Tags: android, asynctaskloader

I have a `SherlockListFragment` that implements a custom `AsyncTaskLoader`.
In the overridden `onStartLoading()`, I have:

```
@Override
protected void onStartLoading() {
  if (mData != null) {
    deliverResult(mData);
  }
  else{
    forceLoad();
  }
}
```

The containing `SherlockListFragment` initiates the loader in `onActivityCreated`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
  mAdapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity());
  setListAdapter(mAdapter);
  getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}
```

and :

```
@Override
public Loader<List<MyData>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
  return new MyListLoader(getActivity());
}
```

The problem is that after 5 activations/navigations to my FragmentActivity, `loadinBackground()` is not called. The `onStartLoding` is called, as well as the `forceLoad`, but that's it.
No Exception, nothing in the LogCat.

Any ideas?

Comment: where/how do you trigger the loader in Activity ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Having a very similar issue.

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I'm having the same issue in my project.

Comment: To those who asked; no, I don't remember having this issue solved, sorry. In that project I ditched the Sherlock component(s) and moved on to the v7 app compat libraries. In that process, much was re-written and I haven't faced this issue again.

Answer (score 3):

It is Ok to call **forceLoad()**.

See what documentation [says](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html#forceLoad()): 
***You generally should only call this when the loader is started - that is, isStarted() returns true.***

Full code:

```
@Override
protected void onStartLoading() {
    try {
        if (data != null) {
            deliverResult(data);
        }
        if (takeContentChanged() || data == null) {
            forceLoad();
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "onStartLoading() ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

## **Important:**

[documentation says](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html): *Subclasses of `Loader<D>` generally must implement at least **onStartLoading(), onStopLoading(), onForceLoad(), and onReset()**.*

AsyncTaskLoader extends Loader but not implements **onStartLoading(), onStopLoading(), onReset()**. You must implement it by yourself!

---

P.S. I was confused with it after experience of using simple CursorLoader, I also thought that using forceLoad() is bad practice. But it is not true.

Comment: You saved my day! You're right, "onStartLoading()" has to be implemented even if it isn't required. Implementing it in my custom AsyncTaskLoader solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Being AsycnTask deprecated, I tried AsyncTaskLoader and seems INCREDIBLE that you need to do this unclear tricks to make it work. Thanks.